# Clone Div When Randomly Chosen More Than Once from Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, cloning

I'm displaying a certain number of divs randomly. However, I want to allow repeating of divs, so I assume I'll need to clone divs that are chosen more than once. I have everything except for the cloning part down, as shown in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ly7pe4n7/

As you can see, if a div is chosen more than once, it only displays the first instance of it. If anyone can provide help cloning when necessary, that would be great. Thanks. Below is the jQuery code so far:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("div.item").css("display", "none");
  var idValues = [];
  var randomValues = [];
  $("div.item").each(function() {
    idValues.push($(this).attr("data-id"));
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    randomValues.push(idValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * idValues.length)]);
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < randomValues.length; j++) {
    group = randomValues[j];
    $('div.item').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("data-id") == group) {
        $(this).css("display", "block");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Edit: I was thinking that I need to insert something like this:

```
if ( $(this).length ) {
        $this.clone().appendTo("#container").css("display", "block");
    }
```

Comment: Your code is only showing / hiding **existing** divs, no creating / destroying / cloning going on.  What is your full desired effect?

Comment: Edited to show what I was thinking for cloning, but Rory answered very well: when a div is chosen more than once, it is shown more than once through cloning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can massively simplify your logic here. Firstlyset up a single pool of `.item` elements which do not change which you can use to select from randomly. Then you can have a single container to append clones of the originals to. Then you can remove the three loops and just have the single loop running which selects a random `.item` `div` for you. Try this:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  var $poolDivs = $('#pool .item');
  var $randomContainer = $('#random').empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $randomContainer.append($poolDivs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $poolDivs.length)).clone());
  }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Ly7pe4n7/1/)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot Rory, that really didn't simplify it. It's just what I was trying to do.